# Understanding the 'AND' Operator in WordPress WP_Query's tax_query

Tags: wp-query

WP_Query is a very rich object but sometimes confusing.
I want to know if these syntaxes mean exactly the same thing: bringing posts that belong on the same time to both categories 76 and 78 (intersection, not 'OR').

1/ Syntax 1

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array(78),
            'operator' => 'IN',
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array(76),
            'operator' => 'IN',
        ),
    ),
));
```

2/ Syntax 2

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array(76, 78),
            'operator' => 'AND',
        ),
    ),
));
```

3/ Syntax 3

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category__and' => array(76, 78)
));
```

Answer (score 3):

They are all convoluted ways of saying the same thing. Syntax 1 is the least efficient method, purely because it takes longer to type and uses unnecessary `IN` clauses when a single clause will do.

All 3 syntaxes are asking WP for posts that have been assigned to both category 76 and 78

Note that if they are not the same as this:

```php
// NOT the same
$wp_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array(76, 78),
            'operator' => 'IN',
        ),
    ),
));
```

Why are there 3 ways of doing it though?

- syntax 1: is basically syntax 2 but more verbose. Part of this is that you're trying to define conditions, and just like human language there's more than one way to write the same thing
- syntax 2: if I were going to write this, this is close to how I'd write it, I'd probably add a post status of publish and add other parameters to try and constrain the search for performance
- syntax 3: `category__and` and the other top level parameters are there because they came first, and for backwards compatibility, as well as ease of use. If you look at the implementation of `WP_Query` you'll see it gets converted into a `tax_query` clause. Note that these top level named conditions are less flexible and limiting compared to the `tax_query` equivalents.

  - you'll also find that for custom taxonomies this becomes even more limiting as the only top level custom taxonomy variable available is deprecated and the documentation directs you to use `tax_query`

Comment: One thing to note during tax_queries is that `include_children` is TRUE by default. It's also worth noting that one wouldn't be able to use `category__and` with a custom taxonomy (likely because of when Tax_Query was introduced)

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I'm not seeing any logic that would differ between `IN` and `AND` in the code, are you sure this would only affect syntax 2 and not syntax 1?